# Apache Beam pipeline with PubSubIO error using Spark Runner PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubReader.getWatermark(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1030)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

A beam pipeline with PubSubIO is running fine as Direct Runner and Dataflow runner, however when I run it on Spark Runner (standalone Spark instance) I get a PubSubUnboundedSource error.

This is the piece of code where I read in from a GCP PubSub subscription, parse the contents contained in the PubSub message into an object with a DoFn, extract event time from the object and window the resulting Pcollection into 20 second windows:

```
// Take input from pubsub and make pcollections of TweetObjects
        PCollection<TweetObj> pubSub_input = pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getPubsubTopic()))
                .apply("ParseTweetFromPubSub", ParDo.of(new ProcessEachElement()))
                .apply("AddEventTimestamps", WithTimestamps.of((TweetObj i) -> new Instant(i.getTimestamp()))
                        .withAllowedTimestampSkew(new Duration(Long.MAX_VALUE))
                ).apply("WindowTweetIntoSeconds",
                        Window.<TweetObj>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(20)))
                                .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                                        .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                                .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(5)))
                                        .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                                .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(5))))
                                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.millis(500))
                                .discardingFiredPanes()


       );
```

I have cross referenced the Beam Runner compatibility matrix and did not find any issues.

This is the error I get when I run this Beam pipeline using Spark Runner (it runs fine with Dataflow and DirectRunner), as per https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/ Spark Runner supports Event Time triggers, which is what I am using.

```
18/01/02 14:53:25 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1514933587500 ms
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 18, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubReader.getWatermark(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1030)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.io.MicrobatchSource$Reader.getWatermark(MicrobatchSource.java:292)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.stateful.StateSpecFunctions$1.apply(StateSpecFunctions.java:180)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.stateful.StateSpecFunctions$1.apply(StateSpecFunctions.java:105)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(StateSpec.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StateSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(StateSpec.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$$anonfun$updateRecordWithData$1.apply(MapWithStateRDD.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$$anonfun$updateRecordWithData$1.apply(MapWithStateRDD.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDDRecord$.updateRecordWithData(MapWithStateRDD.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDD.compute(MapWithStateRDD.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.MapWithStateRDD.compute(MapWithStateRDD.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Show the code. Describe how you run it. More data to investigate the issue.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I have updated my post with the appropriate code snippets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ShahNewazKhan I ran into exact same exception. Were you able to solve it ?